# SATA drive bracket - blank screws

Tags: sata

I just removed a SATA drive bracket from my PC, and the screws are blank!

How do I go about removing these?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those aren't screws.  Notice they are sitting in a slot with two different diameter holes that are connected.  Slide the plastic housing over so the fasteners move into the larger hole, and then they can slide outward with some pulling, allowing them to slip out of the holes in the drive, freeing it from the caddy.